# What is the best torrent client for OSX?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, torrent

What is the best torrent client for OSX ?

utorrent, Transmission, Vuze or ....

?

Comment: Define "best". What are you looking for in a torrent client?

Comment: I just want your opinions like Melwan's opinion.

Comment: @ammarx Other options that may interest you include http://www.xtorrentp2p.com/ and http://www.qbittorrent.org/

Comment: I like Xtorrent.

Answer (score 12):

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/download/) is light and captures the OS X essence. I have been using it for years with no issues. Plus, it's free and open source.

Comment: I'm using utorrent and it's also light and works very well but I want to try transmission because it "captures the OS X essence" then I'll decide.

Comment: I concur : transmission is light and efficient to manage all your torrents. It's free, open-source you can't go wrong giving it a try.

Comment: Transmission's development is a nightmare. For years, Transmission supported Proxies, but one day the developers decided to spontaneously remove support for Proxies without any public discussion. That was 4 years ago and after a lot of outcry Transmission still does not have Proxy support. If your ISP throttles BT traffic (and more and more are these days) then you absolutely need a Proxy, so in that case, Transmission will not be a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

My vote goes to [Deluge](http://deluge-torrent.org), used it for years on Linux and now on OSX. Choose it because it was similar to utorrent.

If you want minimal and effective go with [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com).

I used Vuze many years ago, it was named Azureus then, it was written in java and very slow and unresponsive, I believe that has changed now.

Comment: Why don't you use Transmission?

Comment: I have no idea, I like it better, but old habits die hard and I keep getting back to Deluge :) There will be a day when I just delete Deluge and stick to Transmission :D